# Using printf width specifier with fixed width integer type variable

Tags: c, printf, posix, int32

*w* is a parameter that specifies width of output, *p* is number, that should be printed in octal system
Both variables should be fixed-width integers (uint32_t) (it's a task for my programming class). 
I googled, that I can use macros PRIo32 (inttypes.h) to print int32_t in octal, but I couldn't find any macros for width specifier.
So when I try:

```
printf("%*" PRIo32 "\n", w, p);
```

I get this error in the testing system

> error: field width specifier '*' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int32_t' [-Werror=format=]

Is there any macros, that solves this? Or I should try something else?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. `*` expects an `int`, yet `w` is `int32_t`. You should provide `int` argument. You can cast `w` to `int`.

Comment: But I have to use `int32_t`.  The task specifically says that it's prohibited  to suppoce that int is 4 bytes, and solution that uses `int` was simply rejected

Comment: Then it contradicts itself. You have to pass `int` to `printf` to specify width specifier.

Comment: The `*` modifier always expects type `int`.  Always.  So if you have `w` which you know is `int32_t`, and you cast it to `(int)`, you are not assuming anything about the size of `int` on your machine.  You are assuming that the size of `int` on your machine is the same as the size of `int` on your machine, and that's precisely the same assumption `printf` is making when you use the `*` modifier, so you're golden.  (If `int` is *smaller* than `int32_t` on your machine, and if `w` is greater than 32767, you have a problem, but nobody prints fields that wide, so you should be okay.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the `uint32_t` width to an `int`. [@Kamil Cuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287366/using-printf-width-specifier-with-fixed-width-integer-type-variable#comment102939519_58287366)

```
// printf("%*" PRIo32 "\n", w, p);
printf("%*" PRIo32 "\n", (int) w, p);
```

If necessary, detect extreme cases

```
assert(w <= INT_MAX);
printf("%*" PRIo32 "\n", (int) w, p);
```

No assumptions about `int` range are needed.

---

**Deeper**

Note that a single print with *huge* widths runs into trouble due to *environmental limits*.  Widths above 4095 or so may simply not work.

> Environmental limits 
>   The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least
>   4095.  C17dr § 7.21.6.1 15

Code could use the below to handle pathologically large widths - although it is not efficient.

```
uint32_t w2 = w;
while (w2 > 100) {
  w2--;
  putchar(' ');
}
printf("%*" PRIo32 "\n", (int) w2, p);
```